# "Alligatus ego vinculis vitae" does it translate to "I am bound by the chains of life."

Tags: syntax, word-choice

I was wondering if this translates well. If it does not translate well to mean that phrase, I would appreciate if you  could suggest a way to better phrase it in Latin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be *vinculis*, the ablative of instrument. Your choice of words is very good, I like the alliteration, and *alligo* and *vinculis* fit together very well. There is a word for chained slaves, *alligati*, “the bound ones” (I believe, attested in pl. only).

Speaking of the semantics, you are placing the emphasis on the person who speaks the phrase. “As for me, I am bound *etc.*” If you do not want to emphasize the speaker, you may consider just *sum* in place of *ego*, but metrically *sum* sounds not as good.